# can I have regression tests in jekyll?

Tags: jekyll, regression-testing

Some of the pleasure of writing in markdown is the ability to spread links all over the place (I wish [[link]] worked though).  Odds are that I've made a typo or just plain forgot to actually fill in some of the links.

Is there a way to easily write a regression test inside jekyll that will follow all the (internal) links and tell me if I've missed something?

Answer (score 0):

There probably is... but the easiest way to test this would be to run your website through something like this: https://www.deadlinkchecker.com/website-dead-link-checker.asp